# LEN() returning wrong value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simple data set:

```
230
16000
230
230000
230000
230000
16000000
230000
230000
```

all i want is to get the length of each cell but when i write this code:

```
Sub LengthOfCell()
Dim c As Long
Dim result As Integer

c = ActiveCell.Value
result = Len(c)
Debug.Print (result)


End Sub
```

it gives me 2 for the first cell (230) when it should be 3 and 4 for any number having more than 3 digits. dont know what i am doing wrong. tis is just for proof of concept for a larger SUB:

```
Public Sub SortMyData()

'approach: convert line to string and concatenate to that as it's a lot less picky than Excel's formats, then replace cell value with the new string.
'          Excel will then define the string type as either Percentage or Scientific depending on the magnitude.
Dim i As Integer
Dim N_Values As Integer

N_Values = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            'Range("B6", Range("B5").End(xlDown)).Count

For i = 6 To N_Values 'iteration loop from 6 (first row of value) to N_Values (last filled row)
    Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "0"

    If Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
        Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value / 100

        ElseIf Len(Cells(i, 3).Value > 3) Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000

        ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = Null Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = 0

    Else
        Cells(i, 2).Value
        Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
       ' If Len(Cells(i, 3) > 3) Then
           ' Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000
           ' ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = Null Then
                'Cells(1, 3).Value = 0
       ' Else
           ' Debug.Print
       ' End If
Next

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closing `)` is in the wrong place.

```
If Len(Cells(i, 3).Value > 3) Then
```

should be

```
If Len(Cells(i, 3).Value) > 3 Then
```

`Len(Cells(i, 3).Value > 3)` will evaluate to `Len("True")` or `Len("False")`, so it will always be True (any non-zero number is True)

Comment: i could kiss you right now!!!!.... thanks!... i have been trying to get this to work for a week!... one wrongly placed ")", thats all it was!

Comment: I can't believe nobody noticed that till now.  Good Job!!

Comment: @RaulGonzales dividing the percents by 100 might give you some unexpected results too, because for example the `.Value` of  `123%` is 1.23

Answer (score 5):

> *Len is a **String type function***

@Shai Rado, please, be careful with such statements in answers for newbies...

> F1: Len Function
>   **Returns a Long** containing the number of characters in a
>   string **or the number of bytes required to store a variable**.

Comment: thanks for the correction, I meant since the PO wanted to find the number of characters (digits) in the cell

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for the number of characters (digits) in the cell, you need to change to `Dim c As String` and modify your code a little, it will give you the Result that you are looking for.

See short-sub below:

```
Sub LengthOfCell()

Dim c               As String
Dim i               As Long
Dim result          As Integer

For i = 1 To 9
    c = CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    result = Len(c)
    Debug.Print result
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: that was exatly what i was looking for! thanks!.. so the results that i was getting before were the number of Bytes?

Comment: @RaulGonzales yes, and you are looking for the number of characters (digits) in each cell

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're including the `Dim c As Long` piece at all - why not try this:

```
Sub LengthOfCell()
Dim result As Integer

result = Len(ActiveCell.Value)
Debug.Print (result)


End Sub
```

That works fine for me..

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a confusion between Value and Display Text. `Range().Value` will return the ranges raw value, where as, `Range().Text` or `Cstr(Range().Value)` will return the formatted value.

[image]

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("A2:A9")
        r.Value = 230
        r.Offset(0, 1) = r.NumberFormat
        r.Offset(0, 2) = Len(r.Value)
        r.Offset(0, 3) = Len(r.Text)
        r.Offset(0, 4) = Len(CStr(r.Value))

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: that is what i was looking for. this is the condition i need to check : 
If Len(Cells(i, 3).Text > 3) Then
                Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000
                
            ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = Null Then
                Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
                
        Else
            'Cells(i, 2).Value
            Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If
The problem that i have is that the program is not checking that the cell has 3 characters or less and hence it keeps on dividing by 1000 until it goes to 0 so i dont know what to do?

Comment: @RaulGonzales seems like you just want to check if the number is bigger or equal to 1000 `If Cells(i, 3) >= 1000 Then Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 3) / 1000`

Comment: @Slai Hi Mate, no, i need to know that if the cell contains 3 digits or less it will not be divided by 1000 anymore.
at the moment the program is ignoring that condition adn everytime i run the code it divides everything by 1000?

Comment: @RaulGonzales but what you are saying translates exactly to what Slai wrote.

Comment: @ShaiRado I guess it will depend on his definition of digits. For example 12 versus 1200%